# Xorg won't start after an upgrade to 15.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg, 15.04

I have seemed to run into a dead end with this problem, so I'm seeking any help. I'll preface by stating I have been running 14.04 LTS on my HP Pavilion G6-1b70us for about a year without many problems so I'm happy about that. Upgraded to 15.04 yesterday from 14.04 (first to 14.10) yesterday, since then though I haven't had any success in starting up Xorg server. I can give you all the preliminary information and then maybe you can point me the in right direction.

uname -r

```
Linux myname 3.16.0-46-generic #62~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 11 16:27:16 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lspci | grep 'VGA'

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

lsmod | grep 'video'

```
uvcvideo               81073  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         59104  1 uvcvideo
v4l2_common            15681  1 videobuf2_core
videodev              153793  3 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core
media                  21903  2 uvcvideo,videodev
video                  20128  1 i915
```

So, I gather from here my laptop is using Intel Onboard Graphics and i915 module that the kernel is loading. Then we come to X server.

cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log

[Xorg.log](http://pastebin.com/ee8C2HBL)

The errors happens when X server starts looking for modules, intel, modesetting, etc. So, I assume I need to point it in the right direction with /etc/X11/xorg.conf, but I need to build one from scratch since `X -config` gives me the same errors as /etc/var/Xorg.0.log. So where can I generate an xorg.conf file from scratch? I get an error even trying to create one with `Xorg -config` or even `sudo X :1 -configure`. I'm not sure what to do at this point. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I never resolved this problem and ended up having to reinstall 15.04 from a boot disc. A couple of suggestions for those with similar issues:

1. Check the /etc/apt/source.list. One of the biggest issues I had with this problem was a corrupted files for my Xorg server. But I spent alot of wasted time figuring out why I couldn't `apt-get install xserver-xorg`. My source.list was changed to during the upgrade which prevented me from removing and reinstalling the server.
2. If you get a "dependency" nightmare, you can use `aptitude` instead of `apt-get`. This gave me a better understanding of why I couldn't do a clean remove and install. At this point, I realize that I probably had a few libraries missing or wrong versions of programs. This is where I decided it best to reinstall a fresh copy. In addition, I noticed a couple other programs were giving me problems.
3. Don't be scared to reinstall from disc. 15.04 Ubuntu has an option to reinstall your previous copy without overwriting your personal files. But it never hurts to backup. This version is running great, just needed to reinstall a couple of programs, but I can't complain. Good luck.